# How to set up database relation so that a category may belong to multiple parent category

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I am currently using Laravel (PHP framework) in order to construct an ecommerce site.

The site will have a lot of categories(for products) of which there is ruffly 100-150 and will probably be more as there will be a backend site to add more.

Some times it will be necessary for a category to appear in more than 1 parent category on the site.

**Category Relationships I am trying to achieve:**

- A category can have many child categories.
- A category may have more    than one parent category.

I am very confused as to how to set up the second of these two relationships correctly within Laravel.

**So my question is:**

How do I set up a database structure and Model relations so that a category can belong to many other category without any duplication in the categories table.

I would like to know what tables/columns I need and also what types of relationships need to be set in the models please.

This model seems to work:

I have a table called category_category and relation:

```
  public function parentCategories()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('TottonTimber\Category', 'category_category', 'category_id', 'parent_id');
  }

  public function childCategories()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('TottonTimber\Category', 'category_category', 'parent_id', 'category_id');
  }
```

Yet this doesn't seem like the correct way of doing it as both are "belongsTo"

Comment: I don't see any issues with your setup. This looks fine and as you mentioned works as well. Are you looking for alternative ways of achieving the same?

Comment: I am new to the Laravel framework, and to me it seemed I was "cheating" in doing it this way and may come across problems as a result later on in the project, I expected "childCategories" to have a hasMany relationship yet I couldn't seem to find a way to make that relationship work, however this(relationship that doesn't really make sense) does seem to work and gives me the output I expect.

Comment: In Many to Many to relations. Both models do have a belongs to relation with the other. For example in classic User & Roles Scenerio, User Belongs to Many Roles & Roles Belongs to Many Users.. So as you see 'Belongs to' relationship both sides. Here as you have same model for both ends of your relations, you have to put 'belongsto' for both your relation definations. That is perfectly ok it seems.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships .. Just in case you want to check the example laravel provides for many to many relationships.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this has cleared it all up for me now, I would +1 you but I think I have to have my account for longer than 1 day, so I will when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Many to Many to relations. Both models do have a belongs to relation with the other. For example in classic User & Roles Scenerio, User Belongs to Many Roles & Roles Belongs to Many Users.. So as you see 'Belongs to' relationship both sides. Here as you have same model for both ends of your relations, you have to put 'belongsto' for both your relation definations. That is perfectly ok it seems.